two columns compare to result true false excel
I have tried this formula. it's not working the way I want it to. If there is a matching value in column E and B, I want it to write TRUE or FALSE in column G like below screenshot.
In column E, if the address 192.168.10.22 is present in column B, it will write TRUE, otherwise it will write FALSE.
=VLOOKUP(B2,$E:$E,1,TRUE)
Sample Excel :

thanks,

=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B$7,E2)>0,TRUE,FALSE)?

As far as I understand the problem =B2=E2 should be enough.

Expanding @MGonet formula, I suggest =OR(B2:E13=B2)

The reason why VLOOKUP by itself won't work is that it either 1) returns the value if it finds it (not the same as returning TRUE) or 2) returns #N/A if it doesn't find it (not the same as returning FALSE).
